# Python: How do I detect when a mouse clicks on a image?

Tags: python, pygame, mouseclick-event

Lately I have been working with pygame and I was trying to detect when a mouse clicks over an image. Here is some code that I had but I kept getting a error saying: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'collide_point'. How do I fix the code? Here is the code that I used:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:  
    (x, y) = event.pos  
    if Button_Start.get_rect().collide_point(x, y):  
        print()
```

Answer (score 1):

The attribute is [`collidepoint()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint). There's no underscore.

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:  
    (x, y) = event.pos  
    if Button_Start.get_rect().collidepoint(x, y):  
        print()
```

Comment: I did find another way to detect when a mouse clicked on a picture, but I appreciate the help.

Comment: @J4500 You're more than welcome to post your solution as an answer and accept it. That way everyone can benefit from it.